# Django-Celery - Work in parallel on repetitive requests

Tags: django, django-celery

I am not familiar with Djano-Celery, so I would like to know if it is the right tool for what I need to do before going deeper in the doc.

My django app has a web service for tiling map images that is called like this: http://host.com/tiling/x/y/z.png

xyz are integer variables that are used in the tiling function to compute the output.

**My question is: do Djano-Celery can create workers for parallel processing on this tiling function when repetitive requests are detected?**

For instance, 10 or more requests could be sent by a user at a time : http://host.com/tiling/0/1/1.png, http://host.com/tiling/1/0/1.png etc...

Can Django-Celery creates workers for each in parralel instead of computing each request one by one? What are the requierements on server side? Do I need something linke NGINX or GUNICORN or WSGI or CGI? I am confuse about those things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases celery is used for asynchronous tasks handling. But it works also for concurrent tasks!

By default celery uses multiprocessing but you can also use [Eventlet](http://eventlet.net/) - concurrent networking library for Python.

Reference:

- http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html#concurrency-eventlet
- http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency

Comment: Oh right, I am actually looking into Eventlet doc. Can Eventlet be used without Celery?